# add number as long index in array

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have data like this

`let number = 1000`
`let array = [1,2,3,4,5]`
`let percentage = 5%`

and the output I expected is

`array1 = 1000 + 5%`
`array2 = 1000 + 5% + 5%`
`array3 = 1000 + 5% + 5% + 5%`
`array4 = 1000 + 5% + 5% + 5% + 5%`
`array5 = 1000 + 5% + 5% + 5% + 5% + 5%`

I'm trying add more percentage as the index, I have tried with for loop, but none is working.

can anyone help me with the logic ?
any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. Post that `for` loop that failed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand what you want, but I'm not sure what that is. This code will create a new array where the elements are sum up by the 5% of the previews number.

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5]
let percentage = 0.05 // 5%
let newArr = [1000]

array.forEach((element, i) => { 
  if(i > 0){
    newArr.push(newArr[i-1] + newArr[i-1] * percentage) 
  }
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers in array is irrelevant, so this may be enough. This will generate a new array with percentage base on index

```js
let number = 1000
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let percentage = 5

const foo = array.reduce((acc, el, index) => {
    let result = number
    for (let i = 0; i < index + 1; i++) {
      result = (result / 100) * percentage + result
    }
    acc.push(Math.floor(result))
    return acc
}, [])

console.log(foo)
```